# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 27), indices imply (4, 27) # pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

Here is my numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
num = np.array([[ 0.17899619  0.33093259  0.2076353   0.06130814]
                [ 0.20392888  0.42653105  0.33325891  0.10473969]
                [ 0.17038247  0.19081956  0.10119709  0.09032416]
                [-0.10606583 -0.13680513 -0.13129103 -0.03684349]
                [ 0.20319428  0.28340985  0.20994867  0.11728491]
                [ 0.04396872  0.23703525  0.09359683  0.11486036]
                [ 0.27801304 -0.05769304 -0.06202813  0.04722761]])
```

Here is my header row:

```
days = ['5 days', '10 days', '20 days', '60 days']
```

And here is my first column:

```
prices = ['AAPL', 'ADBE', 'AMD', 'AMZN', 'CRM', 'EXPE', 'FB']
```

I want to put it all in one HTML table like this:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>5 days</th>
      <th>10 days</th>
      <th>20 days</th>
      <th>60 days</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>AAPL</th>
      <td> 0.178996</td>
      <td> 0.330933</td>
      <td> 0.207635</td>
      <td> 0.061308</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>ADBE</th>
      <td> 0.203929</td>
      <td> 0.426531</td>
      <td> 0.333259</td>
      <td> 0.104740</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>AMD</th>
      <td> 0.170382</td>
      <td> 0.190820</td>
      <td> 0.101197</td>
      <td> 0.090324</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>AMZN</th>
      <td>-0.106066</td>
      <td>-0.136805</td>
      <td>-0.131291</td>
      <td>-0.036843</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>CRM</th>
      <td> 0.203194</td>
      <td> 0.283410</td>
      <td> 0.209949</td>
      <td> 0.117285</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>EXPE</th>
      <td> 0.043969</td>
      <td> 0.237035</td>
      <td> 0.093597</td>
      <td> 0.114860</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>FB</th>
      <td> 0.278013</td>
      <td>-0.057693</td>
      <td>-0.062028</td>
      <td> 0.047228</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried to do this way, using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(num, index=prices, columns=days)
html = df.to_html()
print html
```

But when i run this code, i have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2226, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    blocks = [ make_block(blocks[0], axes[0], axes[0], placement=placement) ]
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 967, in make_block
    return klass(values, items, ref_items, ndim=values.ndim, fastpath=fastpath, placement=placement)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 45, in __init__
    % (len(items), len(values)))
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, indices imply 3

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\progfun\finance\file.py", line 261, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\progfun\finance\file.py", line 42, in main
    print (html_table(returns_array, list_of_days, [index] + security_list))
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\progfun\finance\file.py", line 185, in html_table
    df = pd.DataFrame(big_array, index=companies, columns=days)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\progfun\finance\file.py", line 415, in __init__
    copy=copy)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\progfun\finance\file.py", line 561, in _init_ndarray
    return create_block_manager_from_blocks([ values.T ], [ columns, index ])
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\progfun\finance\file.py", line 2235, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    construction_error(tot_items,blocks[0].shape[1:],axes)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\progfun\finance\file.py", line 2217, in construction_error
    tuple(map(int, [len(ax) for ax in axes]))))
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 27), indices imply (4, 27)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: What are the shapes of `big_array`, `companies` and `days`? (e.g. `big_array.shape` etc)

Comment: big_array == num; big_array.shape == (27, 3)

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** Make sure that `big_array` has 4 columns. The shape of `big_array` does not match the shape of your sample array `num`. That's why the example code is working, but your real code not.

---

I was unable to reproduce your error message. On my system (Windows, Python 2.7, pandas-0.11.0, numpy-1.7.1) everything works as expected when running the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

num = np.array([[ 0.17899619,  0.33093259,  0.2076353,   0.06130814],
                [ 0.20392888,  0.42653105,  0.33325891,  0.10473969],
                [ 0.17038247,  0.19081956,  0.10119709,  0.09032416],
                [-0.10606583, -0.13680513, -0.13129103, -0.03684349],
                [ 0.20319428,  0.28340985,  0.20994867,  0.11728491],
                [ 0.04396872,  0.23703525,  0.09359683,  0.11486036],
                [ 0.27801304, -0.05769304, -0.06202813,  0.04722761]])

days = ['5 days', '10 days', '20 days', '60 days']
prices = ['AAPL', 'ADBE', 'AMD', 'AMZN', 'CRM', 'EXPE', 'FB']

print pd.DataFrame(num, index=prices, columns=days).to_html()
```